# How Do I Get A Progress Bar Working for "MediaToolKit" in C#?

Tags: c#

Is there anyways I can generate the progress bar using MediaToolKit?
I have saw the official git-hub page, but unfortunately I was not able to find any resources.

I have tried to make a timer which update in 1 second, but I did not know how to request the time left & calculate how much percentage is done.

Here is my code: (using MediaToolKit & VideoLibrary)

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Convert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var source = @path;
        var youtube = YouTube.Default;
        var vid = youtube.GetVideo(YT_LINK.Text);
        File.WriteAllBytes(source + vid.FullName, vid.GetBytes());

        var inputFile = new MediaFile { Filename = source + vid.FullName };
        var outputFile = new MediaFile { Filename = $"{source + vid.FullName}.mp3" };



        using (var engine = new Engine())
        {
            engine.GetMetadata(inputFile);

            engine.Convert(inputFile, outputFile);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Figuring out what the progress steps are and how to report it back should be that `Convert` function's responsibility. Is `Engine.Convert` your own code? I've done something similar to this once, but there I could predict the output file size, so I just checked that against the current size of the file that was being written to determine how far along it was.

Comment: No, these codes are provided with "MediaToolKit" and "VideoLibrary"
These are the stuff I am using:

using MediaToolkit;
using MediaToolkit.Model;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using VideoLibrary;

Comment: If [this](https://github.com/AydinAdn/MediaToolkit) is the MediaToolkit you mean, the page actually has examples to subscribe to events that give you the conversion progress.

Comment: I have looked at that page, but which is the real one?
Or should I calculate the file Size, and then Calculate the time remaining according to the network speed and all?

Comment: Real one? Look at the "Subscribe to events" example code. `ConvertProgressEventArgs` has `ProcessedDuration` and `TotalDuration` properties. That should be all you need. Alternatively, you can check the amount of frames in the input and use the `Frame` property. Both should give you an accurate measurement of how far the video is progressed.

Comment: Note that to get a progress bar working, you will need to look into multithreading first; you are currently running the conversion process on your UI thread, which will _freeze the form as long as the conversion process is not finished._ This is obviously not ideal for long operations, and completely prevents giving UI updates about the progress.

Comment: Yes, It freezes... I have looked at "ProcessedDuration" and "TotalDuration", but I will only be able to look at "ProcessedDuration" as a time value, which can not convert into it (I wasn't able to), and I am only able to get "TotalDuration" AFTER conversion...

Comment: The durations are just `TimeSpan` objects... nothing special about those. Get its `.TotalMilliseconds` property and you got a usable value. Anyway, the frame count and the media length should be things you can check in advance. And, yes, as I said... look into multithreading. Just look around this place for questions about starting threads or about forms freezing, and you should find sample code in no time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use MediaToolkit's engine events as shown in code below:

```
 using (var engine = new Engine(Constants.targetFfmpegPath))
 {
    engine.ConvertProgressEvent += onProgress;
    engine.ConversionCompleteEvent += onComplete;
    engine.CustomCommand(string.Format(command, input, resolution, crf, output));

 }
```